# php script has facebook data but won't insert it into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, insert

I've been working on this for ~2 days now and can't find a solution after checking my code and error logs for hours. So, I'm hoping some fresh eyes will help.

I'm gathering facebook data and inserting it into my database. When I run a var_dump on the $sql INSERT command I see all the facebook data in the string. I've also run var_dumps on each variable to make sure the data is there. It is and each show as a string type. This matches what the database is expecting--VARCHAR with plenty of room.

I have a few other tables in this database and they are still accepting data so it doesn't seem to be a database issue (this is a shared server and I don't have access to it). Also, I've tried what seems like almost every variation of syntax, different quotes, etc. in the INSERT statement, but to no avail....

Finally, the error I get as a result of mysql_error() is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm just a chill dude looking for some fun . . .','AAAIAZB21He9sBAOLpbm3XTwabMVX0s' at line 1".  What you are seeing in the single quotes (') is the current data for the $fbabout and $at VALUES in the INSERT statement.

With that, here is the code to the php file. Thank you in advance for taking the time to check this out!

```
<?php 
require_once("facebook.php");

$app_id = "";
$app_secret = "";
$my_url = "";



$code = $_POST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
        $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
        . $_SESSION['state']."&scope=email,user_birthday,user_interests,friends_interests,publish_stream,user_about_me,user_checkins";

        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");



} else {
    $host=""; // Host name 
    $username=""; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name=""; // Database name 
    $tbl_name=""; // Table name  

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");  

        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
        . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
        . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);

        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $params['access_token'];

        $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=". $params['access_token'];
    $interests = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/interests?access_token=". $params['access_token'];

    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
    $user_interests = json_decode(file_get_contents($interests));

    $id = $user->id;        
    $fname = $user->first_name;
    $lname = $user->last_name;
    $link = $user->link;
    $gender = $user->gender;
    $locale = $user->location->name;
    $email = $user->email;
    $bday = $user->birthday;

    $uidata = array();
    $number = count($user_interests->data);
            for ($i = 0;$i<=$number-1;$i++){
           array_push($uidata,($user_interests->data[$i]->name));
    }
    $ui = implode(",", $uidata);

    $fbabout = $user->bio;
    $at = $params['access_token'];

    // Insert data into mysql 
    $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(fbid,fname,lname,link,gender,locale,email,birthday,interests,fbabout,fbtoken)VALUES('".$id."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$link."','".$gender."','".$locale."','".$email."','".$bday."','".$ui."','".$fbabout."','".$at."')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);


    if($result) {
        header( 'Location: https://crushonit.com/join/fbRegister.html' );
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

} 
?>

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: The unescaped data is breaking the insert... it is seeing the apostrophe as a closing quote on the data.

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape_string($data)` on all variables about to be inserted into a DB. It prevents SQL injection hacking as well as preventing legitimate problems like these. To see what's happening, try replacing `mysql_query` with `print` and reading what it gives you.

Comment: If you're feeling a little adventurous try rewriting the code in php/PDO. It'll add a few extra days to your project as you GROK the concepts, but the payoff is huge: improved security (injection is impossible), ease of stored procedure functionality, and coding consistency. IMHO mysql_real_escape_string() is so 10 years ago. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: @DudeSolutions, as I mentioned below, I'm pretty new to this so I'm game for learning something that is better right from the start. This all takes me a bit of time so I'm sure learning PDO would be a better use of time in the long run . . . thanks!

Comment: @CarlTimm Absolutely. If the creator of PHP uses it and recommends it, so will I! Another benefit: works with a lot of different SQL engines. So if you switch from MYSQL to POSTGRES, few queries will have to be rewritten, if any. Lastly, another good example that uses PDO extensively--and as a personal aside-- a life changing lesson for me:  http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people have commented, you should always clean any data before inserting it into a database, using mysql_real_escape_string() at the very least. In your case, the "I'm" is causing you problems.

I have another query though; you are using the PHP SDK, by including facebook.php, but you are also manually querying the graph using file_get_contents. This strikes me as odd, because if you are using the SDK you don't need to do that. The SDK will create an object and you query that.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

The above link may be of some help.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick, correct feedback. You're brilliant! As you can probably tell from my code, I'm pretty new to this . . . with that in mind, I didn't use mysql_real_escape on this one because all the data is being pulled from the facebook api and it seemed to me the chances of an injection attack would be low (impossible?) given that. But as I said, I'm new so I clearly don't understand all the uses of mysql_real_escape. I'll read up on that. Thanks again everyone!

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mismatch between the php sdk and my manual calls. I was playing around with a lot of code trying to get this to work, at one point using the php sdk. So that was just a leftover remnant from that . . . thanks again!

Comment: To be honest you are better off, in my opinion, with using the facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0):

$table_name browser reads this as variable remove this $ from table_name

Comment: But `$tbl_name` IS a variable.

Comment: Look at the beginning of the else clause. It is a php variable.